# Why can I populate variables through a std::map before main()?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, undefined-behavior, stdmap

I stumbled across some peculiar behavior in an old program and am figure out why G++ and CLang++ allow it to happen. I have some global variables declared and initialized before main(). The odd part is that they are initialized through a static std::map which is being populated at the same time using the subscripting operator. Everything seems to be in the correct place as soon as main() runs, with the size of the map showing the correct number of populated items as well as the variables containing the values shown before main().

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

static std::map<int, const char*> staticMap;

const char* const a = staticMap[0] = []()->const char* {return "a";}();
const char* const b = staticMap[1] = []()->const char* {return "b";}();
const char* const c = staticMap[2] = []()->const char* {return "c";}();
const char* const d = staticMap[3] = []()->const char* {return "d";}();
const char* const e = staticMap[4] = []()->const char* {return "e";}();

int main() {
    std::cout << "# Items: " << staticMap.size() << '\n' << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Values:\n";
    std::cout << "\"a\" = " << a << '\n';
    std::cout << "\"b\" = " << b << '\n';
    std::cout << "\"c\" = " << c << '\n';
    std::cout << "\"d\" = " << d << '\n';
    std::cout << "\"e\" = " << e << '\n';

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Map Contents:" << std::endl;;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      std::cout << "\t" << staticMap[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result after trying both G++ and CLang (I used the flags -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic-errors):

```
# Items: 5
Values:
"a" = a
"b" = b
"c" = c
"d" = d
"e" = e
Map Contents:
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
```

Is this something inherently allowed in C++? I even went so far as to create my own map type and got the same results but am still not sure if it's behavior I can rely on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is perfectly correct code, albeit a bit unusual. The standard guarantees that globals in the same TU are initialized in declaration order (so `staticMap` will be constructed before the other initializations happen), and including a call to an overloaded operator in an initialization expression is nothing strange.

Actually, all that lambdas stuff is overkill, you could [simply do](http://ideone.com/H7IVB3):

```
const char* a = staticMap[0] = "a";
const char* b = staticMap[1] = "b";
const char* c = staticMap[2] = "c";
const char* d = staticMap[3] = "d";
const char* e = staticMap[4] = "e";
```

Or, [even simpler](http://ideone.com/8PQb2Y):

```
const char *dummy = (
    staticMap[0]="a",
    staticMap[1]="b",
    staticMap[2]="c",
    staticMap[3]="d",
    staticMap[4]="e");
```

In general, you can execute all the code you want before `main` if you define a class for that:

```
class MyCode
{
    MyCode()
    {
        // here be your code
    }
};
static MyCode m;
```

But be careful, debugging code running before `main` starts is often a hairy mess that is best avoided. In all my recent projects, almost no code is run in constructors of global variables, more often I just create the relevant "globals" as locals to `main` and store a pointer to them in global variables.

Comment: Nasty abuse of the comma operator. Love it. Edit: where'd it go ? :(

Comment: @Quentin: actually, needs some more parentheses to avoid confusing the compiler, I'm currently fixing it :)

Comment: That explains a lot. I figured that if it's possible to use this to initialize variables, then I can use it in combination with lambda's to create a factory of sorts for class objects. If this only works for variables in the same TU then does that also mean that I can't extend it through a static library?

Comment: @icdae the order of initialization of globals is only defined within the same TU.  Between TUs the order is undefined.  The `static` local trick can be used to generate less undefined order of initialization, where you wrap your "global" into a function with a `static` local: in C++11, there are extensive guarantees about the initialization of that local.

Comment: Where one discovers the meaning of "less undefined".

Comment: Why is calling a function not allowed but you can still get by with tricks like this?

Comment: @templateboy: calling a function *is* allowed -- otherwise, how would constructors get called?  See [quantdev](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3510483/quantdev)'s answer.

Comment: @Edward: I think he's asking why calling a function at top level in a .cpp is not allowed if it's not in an initializator expression for a global.

Comment: @Edward Yeah but you can't do something like `f()` at namespace scope. Why is that not allowed in the first place?

Comment: I think I can start to see what you mean about undefined behavior in other TU's. It looks like declaring the global map in a static library ("extern...staticMap" in the header and defined in a cpp file), then populating it from another program causes a crash.

Comment: @templateboy: my guess is that the initialization thing is a breach into the spirit of the language (where everything should start at `main`) to allow easier initialization of globals. Having debugged some "impossible" crashes that happened before the `main` (often involving mess deriving from the unreliable cross-TU initialization sequence), I can assure you that abusing this kind of trick is actively looking for ways to harm yourself.

Comment: @templateboy Because static initialization is meant to initialize the global context of the program, nothing more. But to do that with objects, we need to run their constructors. And while we're at it, there's no point in forbidding free functions (that's more or less what a constructor is). But then, a bunch of people far too smart for their own good have tore open the breach and are executing the whole program before `main` even sits on the stack ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: originally I settled with "really" or something like that, but I downscaled the "unusuality" considering that maybe the OP was surprised by the calls in globals initializations, not by that lambda mess.

Comment: @MatteoItalia True, the lambda's were just to reinforce some C++11 answers in case older standards had different quirks for global initialization.

Comment: @icdae : At this point C++11 is an _outdated_ standard; any new `c++` answer at this point will(/should) presume C++11 or C++14. Point being, don't convolute things just to make a minimum standard clear, that's what tags are for. :-]

Answer (score 4):

This is a legal, common technique to execute some code before entering main.
In C++ only *declarations* are allowed at file/namespace scope, but a declaration may contain function calls (the call to `std::map::operator[]` is one)

Your example is effectively identical to :

```
int foo()
{
   std::cout << "foo";  // You could fill your map here 
   return 42;
}

int bar = foo(); // allowed

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

But a more idiomatic C++ way is to use constructors to achieve the same effect :

```
struct foo
{
   foo()
   {
       std::cout << "foo"; // You could fill your map here  
   }
};

foo f;

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

And you can use `foo()` to do your map insertions.

**Note :**

In your example all those lambdas are useless, it could be simplified to :

```
const char* const a = staticMap[0] = "a";
const char* const b = staticMap[1] = "b";
const char* const c = staticMap[2] = "c";
const char* const d = staticMap[3] = "d";
const char* const e = staticMap[4] = "e";
```

Comment: If I try to execute any code before main() using this trick, isn't there a possibility that the compiler would optimize a definition out of the final program or library?

Comment: @icdae: With static libraries, it's possible for initialization code with side effects to be removed, if the linker determines that nothing from that translation unit is needed to satisfy an external.

Answer (score 0):

Variables at namespace scope are initialized before `main()` is entered. The initialization of global variables can call arbitrary functions, either to produce the constructor parameters or from the respective constructor. Once `main()` is exited, these global variables are destroyed in the opposite order.

In theory, you could run the actual program entirely from one of these initializations (or just from the destructor). It is probably not a particular good idea to do so, however.

The code you posted is entirely valid but overly complicated: there is no need to produce the initializers for the strings using lambda functions.